# In PostgreSQL, in a table with multiple rows per unique ID, can you select one row by a condition per unique ID and other values?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate

Specifically, I a table of test data in which I am trying to pick one row of data per student and session (i.e. fall, winter, spring). The problem is that there are some students who re-took the test within the same session, and I would like my query to handle these occurrences.

So let's say a student (with studentid = 12345) took a test **twice** in the fall--Once on September 23rd with a score of 85/100, and then again on October 3rd with a 75/100. I want to know two different queries, one to handle each of the following:

1. Return the row of their **most recent test** (i.e. the test from Oct 3rd)
2. Return the row of their **highest scoring test** (i.e. the test from Sept 23rd)

Here is an example of a table similar to the one I am working with:

```
| studentid | session | testdate     | score | schoolyear |
-----------------------------------------------------------
| ...                                        
| 42532     | Fall    | '2020-10-01' | 68    | '2020-2021'
| 42532     | Winter  | '2021-02-02' | 70    | '2020-2021'
| 12345     | Fall    | '2020-09-23' | 85    | '2020-2021' <--- (this student has two records for the fall)
| 12345     | Fall    | '2020-10-03' | 75    | '2020-2021' <---
| 12345     | Winter  | '2021-01-10' | 79    | '2020-2021'
| 83456     | Fall    | '2020-09-08' | 90    | '2019-2020'
| 83456     | Winter  | '2021-01-18' | 83    | '2019-2020'
| ...
```

So I want to run a query similar to the following:

```
SELECT studentid, session, testdate, score
FROM exam_result
WHERE schoolyear = '2020-2021'
-- (something to filter out the multiples)
```

Where it returns 1 row per student AND session, for **all** students
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just one row, use `fetch` or `limit`:

```
select er.*
from exam_result er
where er.studentid = 12345
order by testdate desc
limit 1;
```

Just adjust the `order by` for the row you want.

For all tests, you would use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (er.studentid) er.*
from exam_result er
where . . . -- whatever other conditions you have
order by er.studentid, testdate desc
```

Comment: No, don't want to only return data for one student. I want all students. So basically a query which answers the following: "Get me data for all students and the test they took in Fall and Winter. But if they took the test multiple times in a session, only return the latest date test (or highest score test)"

Comment: The second part of your answer worked perfectly! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Which score you prefer to have; best or worst or something else? This query gives you the best score. I dropped testdate away because it isn't unique. If you need test date it makes query a bit more complicated. And what date you want if studet gets the same score twice?

```
SELECT studentid, session, MAX(score)
FROM exam_result
WHERE schoolyear = '2020-2021'
GROUP BY studentid, session
```

If you need exam date this this kind of query gives you the first exam date when a student get his highest score. This isn't tested, but you get idea. Make separate subquery which gets min date for student/score combination and join it to your original query.

```
SELECT
 a.student_id.
 a.session,
 b.exam_date,
 a.score
FROM
 exam_resut a JOIN
   (SELECT 
      student_id, session, MIN(exam_date) 
    FROM exam_result 
    WHERE schoolyear = '2020-2021' 
    GROUP BY student_id, session) b 
        ON a.studet_id = b.student_id and a.session = b.sesion
WHERE a.schoolyear = '2020-2021'
GROUP BY a.studentid, a.session, b.exam_date
```